# UWP WebView causing exception

Tags: xaml, webview, uwp

I have a WebView in a Page that is used in a NavigationView. When I swicth to the corresponding tab the following exception is thrown:

Exception thrown at 0x75234662 (KernelBase.dll) in MyApp.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x8001010E : 'DispatcherQueueController is already created on this thread.'.

I determined it was the WebView that causes it through a process of elimination. It still occurs if I replace the xaml for the WebView with a sample from the docs. I.e.:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1" Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>
```

Why is this happening? Might it cause problems? I found it while investigating occasional fatal exceptions from ucrtbase.dll. Might that be related?

Comment: It has stopped happening after I changed the configuration from x86 to x64. Likewise an "Element Not Found" exception that was being thrown somewhere has gone. Same thing reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020682/uwp-community-toolkit-datagrid-onecoreuap-errors

Comment: I create a project with applying the WebView code provided by you in a Page that is used in a NavigationView, but the exception is not reproduced. The project runs well and display the content of the target website. Could you please provided us with a simple sample for testing without any personal and sensitive information by using OneDerive or GitHub? You could refer to [mcve] for a way about how to create a minimal sample.

Comment: Hi YanGu. I've resolved this adequately as per my previous comment. This issue and at least one other appear to happen if you run a UWP app in x86 configuration on an x64 machine.